# Adomian - Example from the book Solving Frontier Problems in Physic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Adomian`s Solving Frontier Problems in Physics: The Decomposition Method book, page 16, 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M2Oy.jpg)

I don`t understand how **u** = $\sum_{m=0}^\infty (L^{-1} k x^p)^m u_0$
could be written.
When I take 2 fold nested integrals of $kx^p$ s I can not come to this equation.

For that reason I can not find the $\phi$1 as stated in the example too. When I try to solve I find some other factors in the denominator.

Thank you

Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is right, the book is wrong. $(L^{-1}kx^p)^mu_0$ has to be read as nested expression
$$
L^{-1}\Bigl(kx^pL^{-1}\bigl(kx^p...L^{-1}(kx^pu_0(x))…\bigr)\Bigr)
$$
Or starting from $u_{m+1}=L^{-1}(kx^pu_m)$ or $u_{m+1}''(x)=kx^pu_m(x)$, $u_m(0)=0=u_m'(0)$
\begin{align}
u_1''&=k(c_1x^p+c_2x^{p+1}+\frac{g}2x^{p+2}\\
\implies u_1&=\frac{kc_1}{(p+1)(p+2)}x^{p+2}+\frac{kc_2}{(p+2)(p+3)}x^{p+3}+\frac{kg}{2(p+3)(p+4)}x^{p+4}\\
u_2''&=\frac{k^2c_1}{(p+1)(p+2)}x^{2p+2}+\frac{k^2c_2}{(p+2)(p+3)}x^{2p+3}+\frac{k^2g}{2(p+3)(p+4)}x^{2p+4}\\
\implies u_2&=\frac{k^2c_1}{(p+1)(p+2)(2p+3)(2p+4)}x^{2p+4}+\frac{k^2c_2}{(p+2)(p+3)(2p+4)(2p+5)}x^{2p+5}+\frac{k^2g}{2(p+3)(p+4)(2p+5)(2p+6)}x^{2p+6}\\
\end{align}
which indeed does not look like the formulas from the book.

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question: If you agree that $u_{m+1}=L^{-1}k x^pu_m$ for every $m\ge0$, then it follows by induction that $u_m = (L^{-1}kx^p)^m u_0$. Therefore $u:=\sum_{m=0} u_m=\sum_{m=0} (L^{-1}kx^p)^m u_0$.

Comment: But I don`t think you can reach at Phi as shown in the example considering the above equation is correct.

Comment: Yes, I agree with LutzL that the book's derivation for $\phi$ does not follow from the above equation.